# How does Grails convert String to Enum?

Tags: grails, groovy, enums, grails-orm

I have a custom `toString` method in my enum:

```
enum TaxRate implements Serializable {
    RATE23(23.0),
    ...

    private String s
    private BigDecimal rate

    private TaxRate(BigDecimal s) {
        this.s = s + "%"
        this.rate = s * 0.01
    }

    public String toString() {
        return s
    }
```

Now when I display the rates in HTML I get nice output like TAX: 23.0%.

But what happens when a user selects the tax from a `<select>` and the sent value is i.e. `23.0%` is that Grails can't create/get the `TaxRate` instance...

What should I override to support this custom mapping? Trying to override `valueOf(String)` ended with a error..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen the entry at the [bottom of this page](http://grails.org/TipsAndTricks)?

> If you want to use a Enum with a "value" String attribute (a pretty common idiom) in a  element, try this:

```
enum Rating {
    G("G"),PG("PG"),PG13("PG-13"),R("R"),NC17("NC-17"),NR("Not Rated")

    final String value

    Rating(String value) { this.value = value }

    String toString() { value }
    String getKey() { name() }
}
```

> Then add `optionKey="key"` to your  tag.

Comment: This works for me on one ENUM but what happens if you have multiple ENUMS that you want to use string values for?